# Java string replacing (remove newlines, change $ to \$)

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like that (`$` character is always surrounded with other characters):

```
a$b
c$d
e$f
```

I want my string method to put a `\` in front of `$` and remove newlines:

```
a\$bc\$de\$f
```

I tried this but it doesn't put `\` character:

```
 s=s.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("$", "\\$");
```

Comment: The first argument to `replaceAll` is a regex, as the docs indicate. The `$` character has meaning in a regex, as any regex tutorial indicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is a reserved character in java `Pattern`s, it indicates the end of line or end of input.

You also need to escape the replacement... thrice.

Try `replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$")`

Answer (score 8):

Use `replace()` method instead of `replaceAll()`. As [Michelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866104/michelle) correctly notes, `replaceAll()` uses regular expressions, that cause problems with `$` character, while `replace()` is literal, which is quite sufficient for your case.

Comment: It may be worth noting why (because `replaceAll()` uses regexes, which OP doesn't need).

Answer (score 2):

Escape `$` like this:

```
s=s.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

`$` is a metacharacter for the first argument of the `replaceAll`method.
This first argument is a regular expression. From a regular expression point of view, `$` means end of line or string.

#### Sample code

```
String s = "a$b\n" +
           "c$d\n" +
           "e$f\n";

s = s.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");

System.out.println(s);
```

#### Output

```
a\$bc\$de\$f
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that '$' is a regular expression *metacharacter*. That is, it has special meaning. Specifically, '$' means 'end of string'.

Since you don't have any metacharacters in your pattern, you can instead use `String.replace()`, which just replaces literal strings.

```
s = s.replace("$","\\$");
```

However, if you *really want to* use `replaceAll()` (for example if other parts of your pattern need to be metacharacters):

If you want to match an actual '$', you need to *escape* the '$' in the pattern to make it a *literal* '$'.

```
\$
```

Then you also need to escape the '\' for Java's quoting, so you end up with:

```
 s = s.replaceAll("\\$","\\$");
```

However, '$' is still a metacharacter in the second parameter, so we need more:

```
 s = s.replaceAll("\\$",Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\$"));
```

Together with your other replacement:

```
 s = s.replaceAll("\\$",Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\$")).replaceAll("\n","");
```

Answer (score 0):

`S` and `\` are special characters :

```
s = s.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

Comment: And how it is different from Mena's answer?

Comment: Don't forget that if you realize after posting that another answer (that's better or the same) has already been posted, there's no cost to deleting your post in order to avoid cluttering questions with answers that don't add anything.